# How to show, that the number-sequence $a_n:=\frac{n^2}{n!}$ is bounded and has monotonicity?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

> How to show, that the number-sequence $a_n:=\frac{n^2}{n!}$ with $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded and has monotonicity?

Boundedness: I observed, that $a_1<a_2>a_3>a_4>a_5>\dots$ That's why I assume, that there is a bound $2=K\geq \mid a_n \mid$ with $K\in\mathbb{N}$. How do I show, that  $a_n$ is actually bounded at $K=2$?

Monotonicity: For $n\geq2$, we show

$\begin{align}
a_n&\geq a_{n+1}\\
\frac{n^2}{n!}&\geq \frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)!}\\
n^2(n+1)!&\geq (n+1)^2\cdot n!\\
(n+1)!&\geq n!
\end{align}$

For $n\leq 2$ we show

$\begin{align}
a_n&\leq a_{n+1}\\
\frac{n^2}{n!}&\leq \frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)!}\\
n^2(n+1)!&\leq (n+1)^2\cdot n!\\
n^2&\leq (n+1)^2
\end{align}$

but that's not really a proof. I don't know how to express formally, that $n!$ increases faster, than $n^2$ for $n\geq 2$ and the other way around for $n\leq 2$.
(Because of the fact, that, $n!$ increases faster, than $n^2$ for $n\geq 2$ and the other way around for $n\leq 2$ it's only important to look at $(n+1)!\geq n!$ or $n^2\leq (n+1)^2$  in the first place.)

Comment: $n \leq 2$ means $n=1$ or $n=2$. You should  use this fact.

Comment: I could just choose $n=1$ and $n=2$ and show, that its true?

Comment: How exactly does $(n+1)! \geq n!$ imply $n^2(n+1)! \geq (n+1)^2 n!$? And the similar thing that you wrote for $n\leq 2$.

Comment: @Ennar that was my question. For large $n$, $n!$ is much bigger than $n^2$ and that's why I thought you can leave it out, but I wasn't really sure how to solve this exactly. As Robert Z pointed out, the proof for $n\geq 2$ should be good but for $n\leq2$ I should just choose $n=1$ and $n=2$ and show that the inequality holds for both $n$'s.

Comment: @Doesbaddel, it's not good, you showed that if the sequence is decreasing, then $(n+1)!\geq n!$, which is trivial, but you didn't show the other direction. I just wanted to point that out, so you are aware where precisely is the mistake in your argument.

Comment: @Ennar oh ok thank your for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct and  for $n\leq 2$ you can simply say that $a_1=1<a_2=2$.
With a little effort we can show more.

For $n\geq 2$: $0<a_{n+1}<a_n$ because
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)!}\cdot \frac{n!}{n^2}
=\frac{n+1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}<1.$$
Since $a_1=1<a_2=2$, it follows that $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}\in (0,2]$ and the maximum value is just $a_2=2$.

By the above estimate we have also that for $n\geq 2$
$$0<a_{n+1}\leq \frac{3}{4}a_n\leq \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{2}a_{n-1}\leq \dots
\leq \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{n-1}a_{2}\to 0$$
and therefore $a_n=\frac{n^2}{n!}\to 0$.

Comment: Why is $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n+1}{n^2}$ although it is $\frac{n+1}{n^2\cdot (n!)^2}$ (if I calculated it correctly)?

Comment: @Doesbaddel Please, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

For $n \geq 4$ we have that $n^2 \leq n!$

Indeed it is true for $n=4$

Now assume that $m^2 \leq m!$ for some $m \in \Bbb{N}$

Then $(m+1)^2 \leq 4m^2 \leq 4(m!) \leq (m+1)m!$ since $m\geq 4$

For $n=1$ the value of the sequence is $1$

For $n=2$ the value is $2$

For $n=3$ the value is $\frac{9}{6}<2$

So the sequence is bounded by $K=2$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n\ge 2$ you already have a proof, then for $n\le 2$ just consider $n=1$ and $n=2$ and this complete the [**proof by exhaustion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_exhaustion).